# Problems with RPM (JRE)

Tags: ubuntu, rpm

I'm trying to install a JRE on Ubuntu 10.04, but I failed:

```
oneat@oneat-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo rpm -i --force-debian jre-6u21-linux-i586.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/basename is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/cat is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/cp is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/gawk is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/grep is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/ln is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/ls is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/mkdir is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/mv is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/pwd is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/rm is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/sed is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/sort is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/touch is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/cut is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/dirname is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/expr is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/find is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/tail is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/tr is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /usr/bin/wc is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
    /bin/sh is needed by jre-1.6.0_21-fcs.i586
```

How can I work around that?

---

**Edit**: I tried [Riccardo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/problems-with-rpm-jre/2582#2582), but it still doesn't work:

```
root@oneat-desktop:/home/oneat/Downloads/untitled folder# rpm --nodeps --force-debian -i jre.rpm
Unpacking JAR files...
    rt.jar...
    jsse.jar...
    charsets.jar...
    localedata.jar...
    plugin.jar...
    javaws.jar...
    deploy.jar...
[: 924: /usr/java/jre1.6.0_21: unexpected operator
[: 924: /usr/java/jre1.6.0_21: unexpected operator
```

Those are only some of the errors:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjava.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: couldn't find library libjvm.so needed by debian/jre/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386/libj2gss.so (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386').
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjava.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjava.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: couldn't find library libjvm.so needed by debian/jre/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386/libjava.so (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386').
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libverify.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libverify.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: couldn't find library libjvm.so needed by debian/jre/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386/libjsoundalsa.so (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386').
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjava.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjava.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjli.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: Can't extract name and version from library name `libjli.so'
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: couldn't find library libmawt.so needed by debian/jre/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386/libjawt.so (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386').
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: couldn't find library libjvm.so needed by debian/jre/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386/libjawt.so (ELF format: 'elf32-i386'; RPATH: '/usr/java/jre1.6.0_21/lib/i386').
```

Comment: On which system is this?

Comment: UBUNTU 10.04 LTS

Comment: I merged your answer into your question; in the future you can just [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/2556/edit) your question if you need to provide more information

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running Ubuntu, can't you just install a JRE that comes from Ubuntu repositories?  E.g., `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre` (which is presently at version `6.20dlj-1ubuntu3`).

If you still need to go down the RPM route, you have two options:

1. tell `rpm` to ignore those dependencies (`rpm --nodeps -i ...`), since all those listed are
   programs that are already installed on a standard Ubuntu system.
   (The only mismatch is `gawk`, which is `/usr/bin/gawk` on Ubuntu,
   but `/bin/gawk` in the dependency output; you can either make
   symlink -to be on the safe side- or just ignore it and hope the
   JRE scripts do not hard-code the path to `gawk`.)
2. Use [alien](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/) (`sudo apt-get install alien`) to convert the `.rpm`
   file into a `.deb` one; this should also fix dependencies or let
   you correct them.